# how to execute Jenkins job in non-sequence manner?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I have 10 jobs in jenkins 1 to 10, but I want to execute the job number 5th and 10th first and the rest others and so on, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute one job after another has run, just configure a build trigger to execute when another project has been built. Jenkins will mark the jobs as upstream/downstream projects.

If you want to prevent that some job executes while some other job is running (even if triggered manually on the UI), use the [Lockable Resources Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/lockable-resources/).